# PHP letting the code add the uploader's last name to the image file he is uploading from a form

Tags: php

Got the server, got the domain, got the code, getting the images successfully, making the products for the customers from the image files they upload. Yay!

Problem: all my image names are image_0001 etc.

Customers can't rename image files from iPhones and do not care to from PCs.

So I was thinking about putting a short form on the upload page asking for customer's last name and having the PHP code attach that name to the image file(s) being uploaded.

If it's not possible, I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Sounds good, what do you have so far?

Comment: form class="form" action="/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="20971520">
<label for="filename">Select File:</label>
<input type="file" name="filename[]" id="filename" multiple
data-maxfiles="20"
data-postmax="50331648"
data-displaymax="48.0 MB">
</p>

Answer (score 0):

You can rename files after they have been saved to your server, check out the PHP manual for the rename function - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php, or just while you are moving them from the tmp directory, you can specify a different name for the uploaded file.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Be careful to include something in your code for dealing with naming conflicts.

Comment: Thanks but thats the problem reworded. I need to know which files on my server go to which customers.

Answer (score 0):

This one might help :

```
$imagename = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = pathinfo($imagename , PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //we want to change the file name but not the extension
$newImagename= $imageName.$username.'.'.$ext;  //assuming you hold the username in $username

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/path/{$newImagename}")) 
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've search google up down and sideways and usually am a really great searcher, so others tell me. But i have nightmares of sending a little old man pic covered in pink hearts and sprinkles to a five year old girl exclaiming, "happy fifth birthday!" i really need to better match the file names to the customer lol thanks again, holly